# Trying to return a structure pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am using an **assign()** function to assign memory for a structure which I'm storing in the structure pointer variable `l`.
But when I run this code there is an error saying:

> 'return' was not declared in this scope.

**Code**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
typedef struct list {
        int a;
        char c;
    };

list *assign();
int main() {
   list *l;
   l = assign();
   l->a = 20;
   printf("%d",l->a);


   return 0;
}
list *assign() {
    list *ptr = (list*)malloc(sizeof(list));
    reutrn ptr;
}
```

Comment: Change `reutrn ptr;` to `return ptr;`.

Comment: Remember to `free` the memory once you're done... even better, separate the memory concern from the functionality. If you need a constructor/destructor, write them both in. By separating concerns you will be writing clearer and cleaner code, thereby minimize the risk of memory leaks as your project grow.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
        int a;
        char c;
    }list;

list *assign();
int main() {
   list *l;
   l = assign();
   l->a = 20;
   printf("%d",l->a);


   return 0;
}
list *assign() {
    list *ptr = (list*)malloc(sizeof(list));
    return ptr;
}
```

You misspelled return and you didn't give a name for your struct.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote 'reutrn' instead of 'return' in your code. Check your last few lines.